# Facing issue while loading Parent Tree structure in JAVA J2ee

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tree, treeview, tree-structure

Facing issue while loading Parent Tree structure in JAVA J2ee . It becomes very slow while loading .  Can we use any plugin for that because data is huge .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a JSF framework such as [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) or [RichFaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/) or [IceFaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/overview.jsf) can help you with lazy loading of a tree structure.

Example given: [Tree - Basic](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml).